# Calculate cumulative product based on date by category

Tags: r, data.table

I want to add a new column to my data.table containing the cumulative product of `Data1` based on the `Date`. The cumulative product should be calculated for each category (`Cat`) and should start with the latest available `Date`.

Sample data:

```
     DF = data.frame(Cat=rep(c("A","B"),each=4), Date=rep(c("01-08-2013","01-07-2013","01-04-2013","01-03-2013"),2), Data1=c(1:8))
     DF$Date = as.Date(DF$Date , "%m-%d-%Y")
     DT = data.table(DF)
     DT[ , Data1_cum:=NA_real_]
     DT

        Cat      Date Data1 Data1_cum
     1:  A 2013-01-08     1    NA
     2:  A 2013-01-07     2    NA
     3:  A 2013-01-04     3    NA
     4:  A 2013-01-03     4    NA
     5:  B 2013-01-08     5    NA
     6:  B 2013-01-07     6    NA
     7:  B 2013-01-04     7    NA
     8:  B 2013-01-03     8    NA
```

The result should look like this:

```
        Cat      Date Data1 Data1_cum
     1:  A 2013-01-08     1    1
     2:  A 2013-01-07     2    2
     3:  A 2013-01-04     3    6
     4:  A 2013-01-03     4    24
     5:  B 2013-01-08     5    5
     6:  B 2013-01-07     6    30
     7:  B 2013-01-04     7    210
     8:  B 2013-01-03     8    1680
```

I figured out that I could do something similar using `cumprod()`, but I do not know how to handle the categories. `NA`s in `Data1` should be ignored / treated as 1.
The real dataset has about 8 million rows and 1000 categories.

Comment: you say there are 8M entries with 1000 categories. That means you've got about 8000 entries per category. Even if the smallest value is 2, the cumulative product would max to be 2^8000, isn't it? Wouldn't most of your values just be Infinity?

Comment: Yes, but fortunately there are primarily `NA`s and most numbers smaller than 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only  looksissue is the ordering...

```
DT[order(Date, decreasing=TRUE), Data1_cum := cumprod(Data1), by=Cat]
DT
   Cat       Date Data1 Data1_cum
1:   A 2013-01-08     1         1
2:   A 2013-01-07     2         2
3:   A 2013-01-04     3         6
4:   A 2013-01-03     4        24
5:   B 2013-01-08     5         5
6:   B 2013-01-07     6        30
7:   B 2013-01-04     7       210
8:   B 2013-01-03     8      1680
```

---

#### However, if you have NA's to deal with, then there is a few extra steps:

**Note:  If you shuffle the order of the rows, your results can vary.  Careful with how you implement the `order(.)` command**

```
  ## Let's add some NA values
  DT <- rbind(DT, DT)
  DT[c(2, 6, 11, 15), Data1 := NA]

  # shuffle the rows, to make sure this is right
  set.seed(1)
  DT <- DT[sample(nrow(DT))]
```

Assigning the cumulative product:

#### Leaving NA's

```
## If you want to leave the NA's as NA's in the cum prod, use: 
DT[ , Data1_cum := NA_real_ ]
DT[ intersect(order(Date, decreasing=TRUE), which(!is.na(Data1))) 
      , Data1_cum := cumprod(Data1)
      , by=Cat]

# View the data, orderly
DT[order(Date, decreasing=TRUE)][order(Cat)]

     Cat       Date Data1 Data1_cum
  1:   A 2013-01-08     1         1
  2:   A 2013-01-08     1         1
  3:   A 2013-01-07     2         2
  4:   A 2013-01-07    NA        NA  <~~~~~~~  Note that the NA rows have the value of the prev row     
  5:   A 2013-01-04     3         6
  6:   A 2013-01-04    NA        NA  <~~~~~~~  Note that the NA rows have the value of the prev row
  7:   A 2013-01-03     4        24
  8:   A 2013-01-03     4        96
  9:   B 2013-01-08     5         5  
 10:   B 2013-01-08     5        25
 11:   B 2013-01-07     6       150
 12:   B 2013-01-07    NA        NA  <~~~~~~~  Note that the NA rows have the value of the prev row  
 13:   B 2013-01-04     7      1050
 14:   B 2013-01-04    NA        NA  <~~~~~~~  Note that the NA rows have the value of the prev row    
 15:   B 2013-01-03     8      8400
 16:   B 2013-01-03     8     67200
```

#### Replacing NA's with value of previous Row

```
## If instead you want to treat the NA's as 1, use: 
DT[order(Date, decreasing=TRUE), Data1_cum := {Data1[is.na(Data1)] <- 1;  cumprod(Data1 [order(Date, decreasing=TRUE)] )}, by=Cat]

# View the data, orderly
DT[order(Date, decreasing=TRUE)][order(Cat)]

    Cat       Date Data1 Data1_cum
 1:   A 2013-01-08     1         1
 2:   A 2013-01-08     1         1
 3:   A 2013-01-07     2         2
 4:   A 2013-01-07    NA         2   <~~~~~~~ Rows with NA took on values of the previous Row
 5:   A 2013-01-04     3         6
 6:   A 2013-01-04    NA         6   <~~~~~~~ Rows with NA took on values of the previous Row
 7:   A 2013-01-03     4        24
 8:   A 2013-01-03     4        96
 9:   B 2013-01-08     5         5
10:   B 2013-01-08     5        25
11:   B 2013-01-07     6       150
12:   B 2013-01-07    NA       150   <~~~~~~~ Rows with NA took on values of the previous Row
13:   B 2013-01-04     7      1050
14:   B 2013-01-04    NA      1050   <~~~~~~~ Rows with NA took on values of the previous Row
15:   B 2013-01-03     8      8400
16:   B 2013-01-03     8     67200
```

---

Alternatively, If you already have the cumulative product and simply want to remove the NA's you can do so as follows:

```
# fix the NA's with the previous value
DT[order(Date, decreasing=TRUE),
      Data1_cum := {tmp <- c(0, head(Data1_cum, -1));  
      Data1_cum[is.na(Data1_cum)] <- tmp[is.na(Data1_cum)]; 
      Data1_cum }
      , by=Cat ]
```

Comment: Thank you Ricardo and Simon. I don't want `NA`s in the cum column, but I'm not sure yet, which of your solutions to choose for treating the `NA`s. I think replacing them upfront could be more efficient when using the `Data1` multiple times in a similar way.

Comment: @Cake, replacing them is fine.  The issue is ordering them.  When using toy sample data where the columns are already ordered, the results are different than if your columns are out of order.

Comment: setting the key to `date` unfortunately will not address this because it would be the reverse order

Comment: Isn't the answer just: `DT[is.na(Data1), Data1 := 1L][order(Date, decreasing=TRUE), Data1_cum := cumprod(Data1), by=Cat]` or am I missing something?

Comment: @Arun, if you are changing the original data, then yep.  I was working under the impression that the original data was to be preserved

Comment: @Ricardo: Yes, thank you. I got the ordering issue when I read your solution.

Comment: Just duplicate the column then (or) create a boolean value for NA entries to replace them back...